# I’m using the L293D IC as a driver, controlled by an Arduino board. Should I be worried about setting both inputs low?

Tags: l293d

Should I be worried about setting both inputs high? It seems that the simulation I made with Tinkercad doesn’t care of a short circuit happening, that’s why I need a word from an expert

---

[image: Here the schematic]

I posted the schematic, hoping that this could further explain

Comment: That depends on what are you driving. Could you show some schematics or detailed description?

Comment: Your schematic looks like it lacks some (vertical) lines. Problem in the export?

Comment: It was automatically made by Tinkercad. Those lines are absent because are different parts of the circuit ( the one below I assume is a detailed schematic for buttons connected to Arduino pins)